# Visual Studio 2010 workaround to target .NET 4.5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.5

Is there some workaround to target .NET 4.5 from Visual Studio 2010?

I know there is no official support for this, but still, I'm hoping somebody discovered some clever way to get around this.

I know you can install 4.5 as an in-place replacement for 4.0 and your solutions will work, but I want to specifically target 4.5.

Comment: Given that I asked my question 9 days before that, maybe that question should be the duplicate? :)

Comment: Yes, that is usually the case. But in this case I think the number of answers (there is effectively only ***one*** answer for this one), the comprehensiveness of the answers and the number of votes would make the other question the canonical one.

Comment: BTW: Isn't it 3 months before (and the first answer 2 1/2 month before)?

Comment: The thing is, the accepted answer on the other question says it cannot be done, while the same question has an answer with the correct solution that shows how can be done. And that answer is linked here as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking around for this for a while too. It seems there is no plausible workaround except to upgrade to Visual Studio 2012. I've created a VM with the Visual Studio 2012 development environment and have been working on that and Visual Studio 2010 in another.